# Can views make AJAX calls in MVC pattern?

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller, single-page-application

The MVC pattern is pretty clear to me. The model is independent of the view, represents data and forwards it to the view to show. But I have one question. For feasibility, is it okay to make AJAX calls to the database from the view? Or should I refactor my code to make AJAX calls only from the models and then forward it to the view?

Comment: Ajax calls are by definition made from the live html document in the browser to a backend server. You wouldn't do Ajax calls "to the database" though, but to a server side endpoint that functions as part of a controller. To get a more detailed answer you need to describe in detail your system architecture.

Comment: @NineBerry I thought it was obvious that I make a call to my back-end endpoint :p To explain my little program in detail now. For example, on search icon click I have a function that runs in a procedural way, the view fetches values from the inputs and then a model is created with these values. The model makes ajax calls with these values to endpoints and gets the data. It then forwards the data to the view to render on screen. This example works great without any AJAX calls from my view, but in other examples I have to make an AJAX call before I initiate my model class.

Comment: @NineBerry Could the solution be to just create static methods on my model that make these AJAX calls?

Comment: We don't even know what technology you use. Are you using Asp.net MVC or some PHP based framework or Java-based or ... There's hundreds of framework that implement the model-view-controller pattern.

Comment: @NineBerry Exactly. You are either using wrong terminology or terminology specific to your project because it is hard to understand. Can you please share some code of controller and then proceed? You can update the question. That way more people will be able to answer. People tend to ignore vague questions especially if they are programmers.

Comment: @NineBerry Vanilla javaScript, but what significance does this provide to my question?

Comment: The terminology I'm using is pretty general. I have a model,view and controller. There is one spot in my code where I have to make an AJAX call before I initiate my model class to render some important data on screen which means I had to make the AJAX call from my view.

Comment: So you have implemented the MVC pattern within the javascript code? Model, View and Controllers are all in the client-side JavaScript?

Comment: @NineBerry Yes.

Answer (score 0):

Database is accessible to view through controller in MVC so your AJAX call must be directed to a controller action which will then access the database so we can imply that you cannot make a call from the view.

Comment: How does my controller have access to the DB? I am confused now, where do I write my axios code?

Comment: In my model, if I am not mistaken?

Comment: Controller has access to the model primarily which can access or change the value in database.
Diagram here will help you better probably:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller

Comment: Exactly, the model creates axios calls and stores them in class values for example and this is accessible for the controller?

Comment: You are either using wrong terminology or terminology specific to your project because it is hard to understand. Can you please share some code of controller and then proceed? You can update the question. That way more people will be able to answer. People tend to ignore vague questions especially if they are programmers.